# How far back does a DataGridView's BindingSource update?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, bindingsource

When I first started working on this project I had never worked with anything .NET, much less C# or WinForms, so if any of what I've done is bringing you to the point of tears, please let me know what the best practice would be for this set up.

I am working on a scheduling system. I have the events in a database and I get those from a web service onto a master list for the application to use. This Event class contains a list of activities (List):

```
[Global class]

public List<Event> Events = Service.GetEvents();
```

I have a DataGridView that displays the events and a second Datagridview that displayed the event activities. I also have a "Save" button that would only be enabled if an event had changed in any way. Here's how I have that set up:

```
[EventsView form]

BindingSource eventsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
BindingSource activitiesBindingSource = new BindingSource();

List<Event> events = new List<Event>(Global.Events.ToList());

eventsBindingSource.DataSource = events;
activitiesBindingSource.DataSource = ((Event)eventsBindingSource.Current).Legs //updated when clicked on new row.

eventsDataGridView.DataSource = eventsBindingSource;
activitiesDataGridView.DataSource = activitiesBindingSource;
```

I have it set so that when the CellValueChanged on the avtivitiesDataGridView, it would check the activitiesBindingSource.Current, look-up the activities for that event in the original Global.Events list and if it differs it would enable the "Save" button.

However, when I check to see if the values differ, lo and behold, the Global.Events list has already been updated, even though the BindingSource is set to the events list, which is a copy of that list.

Does BindingSource have it so that if the list is a copy, it would update the original as well?

The reason why I don't want it to update it automatically and save it is so that I can update the web service when the user clicks save only.

I've also tried the following:

- Having the (copy) events list be a BindingList
- Copying the events from the global list one by one
- bypass the BindingSource and setting the DGV's datasource to the List

This used to work when I had Global.Events be a different class that I used for the sole purpose of transfer between the web service and the application (because the Entity Framework would have collections that  could not pass through), but since I've changed that list to have the already-converted Event objects it had been able to update it that far automatically.

Is there a UpdateMode similar to the one in DataBindings where I could set it not to update unless I tell it to? Or am I just going at this all wrong?

Thank you for your help, let me know if you need more details about this.

Answer (score 1):

When the data is bound to the DataGridView, the DGV doesn't care much what the Events are stored in. Whether you're using the original (Global) list of Events or even manually copying the list, the fact of the matter is that the Event objects are the same throughout and therefore, when the user makes changes (through the DGV), the original Events change.

One way of implementing this "Saving" model would be to:

1. Clone the original Events from the global list (consider implementing [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
2. Setup the DataSource of the DGV to point to these cloned Events.
3. When a "Save" is performed, match up the original Events to the cloned Events (possibly through a unique identifier) and copy the changed information to the original Events.

Comment: I tried doing this, but the issue persists. I think I might have something hidden somewhere since this form's code is quite extensive. And I do reset the DataSource when the selected Events changes. I will try to separate it into Controller and View, and see if I can find where the issue lies. Thank you so much for the advice, though, I will keep the cloned lists as a good precaution.